MAKING ISO IMAGE-STICK
I am trying to make a stick of ISO image of Ubuntu 22.04 lts bootable. Tried to use UNetbootin but couldn´t. I've read that Ubuntu 22.04 does not work with it.
Also tried to use Disk Creator but it doesn't work either.
I need the stick because have to download /home, because have to change partitions on Gparted.
When I installed Ubuntu for the first time, years ago, I was wrong with partitions and now my /home is nearly full.
Please, what can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Untebootin works. Startup Disk Creator works. Lots of methods work. There is not enough information in this question for us to understand why you might be having problems. "couldn't" and "doesn't work" are not detailed enough. You are more likely to get useful help if your question shows actual errors or feedback.

https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy is the best, personally speaking.

E: El repositorio «https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.

Here the translation: The repository 'ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file. N: It cannot be updated from a repository like this safely and is therefore disabled by default. N: See the apt-secure(8) man page for details on creating repositories and configuring users.

Hopefully, you've made a backup of all of your important files on an external device (or a cloud you trust) before you reload your OS. All files will be gone if you reload the OS and repartition your HDD.
As far as burning an image of Ubuntu to a USB memory stick, I've had good luck using Balena Etcher - it's very simple and easy-to-use. If you're using Windows, try Rufus. Both are good apps for 'burning' an ISO image to a ~4GB or bigger USB Key.
Make sure the USB key does not have any important files, first, as it will be erased!

You can improve the question by omitting the first paragraph  "Hopefully...:" The OP seems to know this already. The OP stated in the question "I need the stick because have to download /home, because have to change partitions on Gparted"

I will try Balena Etcher. Thanks.
